# No systemctl services are working

Tags: apt, bash, permissions, ssh, dpkg

I am not sure if this title is even right for this problem.
Problem started from yesterday. I had to install Mega raid manager in my system. Therefore I asked the supplier to provide its source files to install. They sent me rpm files for lib and mega raid manager. I wasn't able to install them. Therefore I again contacted them and the service guy told me five steps to install them. First he asked me to install alien service.

Which I did using following command.

```
sudo apt-get install alien*
```

It went smoothly, everything installed. After that he asked me to convert my rpm files into deb using following commands

```
sudo alien -k --script Lib_Utils2-1.00-08.noarch.rpm
sudo alien -k --script MegaRAID_Storage_Manager-17.05.00-02.noarch.rpm
```

Again it went smoothly

After that I had to install these deb files therefore I ran following command:

```
sudo dpkg -i lib-utils2_1.00-08_all.deb
```

It generated a warning:

```
dpkg: warning: downgrading lib-utils2 from 1.00-9 to 1.00-08
```

same happened with next command:

```
$ sudo dpkg -i megaraid-storage-manager_17.05.00-02_all.deb
dpkg: warning: downgrading megaraid-storage-manager from 17.05.00-3 to 17.05.00-02
```

Right after that system started behaving abnormally, I had to start some service from `/etc/init.d` using `sudo`, but after pressing `/et` when I was pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>, instead of completing the path it started showing the following message:

```
sudo /et-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied bash: _upvars: `-a2': invalid number specifier
-bash: /dev/null: Permission denied bash: _upvars: `-a0': invalid number specifier
```

In this command I pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd> two times and therefore both times it showed some invalid number specifier, it never happened before I tried it several times but every time I got same message. Therefore I logged out of the system and tried to log in again using ssh but this is where all the headache started every time I log in I wasn't able to. I was getting the following message:

```
$ ssh -X scbb@192.168.4.111 

scbb@192.168.4.111's password:

X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0 Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-51-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com  * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com  * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage


 * Canonical Livepatch is available for installation.
   - Reduce system reboots and improve kernel security. Activate at:
     https://ubuntu.com/livepatch

334 packages can be updated. 167 updates are security updates.

Failed to connect to https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts. Check your Internet connection or proxy settings

Last login: Mon Sep  9 12:52:13 2019 from 192.168.4.218 Could not chdir to home directory /home/scbb: Permission denied /bin/bash: Permission denied Connection to 192.168.4.111 closed.
```

Than I restarted the system from the power button, but as soon as it started it got stuck on the following screen:

[image: Stuck screen]

On this screen no key is working nothing is happening. The system provider is saying I did something wrong, I am sure I haven't done anything wrong. However this system is on Raid0 and Raid6 therefore as a final solution we can re-install its OS but is there a chance to fix this problem without re-installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it, using Ctrl+Alt+F2 I logged into terminal right before above showed screen appears. Because on that screen I couldn't do anything. After entering into terminal I tried to login using sudo user but it stucked into a loop. I mean I was entering correct password but again and again it was asking for login and password. It happened with me 3-4 month on another system but at that time it was on GUI. But this time I was already in terminal mode. Therefore I entered

```
User: root
Password: sudo user password
```

And finally I entered into system. First of all I checked the permissions of / folders
It all seems messed up than I also checked it this is messed up only in parent directory or in recursive/child directories also. But it appeared that it was only for parent folders only. Therefore from another system which was working perfectly I checked the permissions for all / directories. And converted them into numeric form using following command

```
stat -c %a /lib/
stat -c %a /bin/
stat -c %a /proc/
```

........ so on
Using those numeric permission I have changed the permission of corrupted system's directories.
like:

```
chmod 755 /bin
```

Remember I checked the recursive directories as well but there wasn't any messing up, that's why I didn't use any R option in chmod.

Once all permission changed all seems to work flawlessly as before.